# How To Remove "null" Word From My Output?

Tags: java, string

```
import java.util.*;
public class Words_Array {

    public int numberWords(String str) {   //to store the number of words in the given sentence
        int l = str.length();
        int w = 0 ; 
        for(int i = 0 ; i < l ; i++)
            if(str.charAt(i) == ' ')
                w++;
        return (w+1);
    }

    public String[] storeWords(String str , int w) {    //to create an array which contains the words of the sentence
        int l = str.length();
        String arr[] = new String[w];
        w = 0 ; 
        int i = 0;
        do {
            if(str.charAt(i) != ' ')
                arr[w] = arr[w] + str.charAt(i);
            else
                w++;
            i++;
        }
        while(i < l && w < arr.length);
        return arr;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Words_Array obj = new Words_Array();

        System.out.print("Enter The Sentence : ");
        String sent =  in.nextLine();

        int w = obj.numberWords(sent);
        String Words[] = obj.storeWords(sent, w);

        for(int i = 0 ; i < w ; i++)
            System.out.println(Words[i]);
    }

}
```

**If My Sentence is : I am Saikat Das
then the output is coming as :

```
nullI
nullam
nullSaikat
nullDas**
```

**how Can I fix this Logical error**

Comment: Please edit to include what it is you want this code to do?

Comment: i new here so i couldnt understand your point

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Those `null` values most likely come from you adding something to a string or directly printing something that is null - `"null"` is the result for `String.valueOf(null)`.

Comment: yeah !!! But My Question Is How Can I Remove This ... "null"

Comment: "null" appears in output when the string variable you've provided is null; this is different than the string variable being an empty string, represented by "". Since the code you've given us does not have the part that does the output, we can't tell what it is doing, or even what you want to do. When writing a question, remember that your readers have no context other than what you give them.

Comment: @arcy: The given code is complete and reproduces the problem.

Comment: how can i Post The Output ???

Comment: Side note: you could get the same desired output with `String words[] = sent.split(" ");` - that would not have that much of a learning effect though (and of course the regex could handle even more cases ;) ).

Comment: yeah i know but my School Doesnt allow us to Use That Method...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this line: `arr[w] = arr[w] + str.charAt(i);` and think about what happens if `arr[w]` is `null` - you'll basically generate a value `null + charAt(i)` which results in the string `"nullX"` (where `X` is that character).

When the next character (let's say `'Y'`) is added you basically do something like `arr[w] = "nullX" + 'Y'` and thus get a new value of `"nullXY"`.

To get rid of this you need to initialize the array you've created with something other than the default value (which is `null`):

```
String arr[] = new String[w];
Arrays.fill( arr, "" ); //set all elements to contain an empty string
```

Alternatively handle the `null` case when adding characters:

```
arr[w] = (arr[w] == null ? "" : arr[w]) + str.charAt(i);
```

Comment: @SaikatDas you're welcome. If the answer helped feel free to vote and accept :)